# Styling GeoJSON polygons loaded via a URL in javascript, MapBox

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, mapbox

Below is a little bit of code that produces two polygon layers displayed as gray, semitransparent shaded polygons by default:

```
var overlays = {
  SeniorsNorm: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('data/SeniorsAge65+.geojson'),
  AQIRiskZones: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('data/AQIZones.geojson'),
};
```

Would it be possible to assign a fill color, opacity, etc? Have tried just about everything and I just can't quite get there. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `L.mapbox.featureLayer` is as follows:

> L.mapbox.featureLayer(id|url|geojson, options)

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.4/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-l-mapbox-featurelayer

Which means you can pass the URL directly to it as the first parameter so you don't need to use `loadURL`. You can use that if later on want to reload or load another URL. To set style on the layer's features you can use the `setStyle` method as described in the documentation for `L.FeatureGroup` which `L.mapbox.featureLayer` is extended from:

> Sets the given path options to each layer of the group that has a setStyle method.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-setstyle

Which would boil down to something like this:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer('data/SeniorsAge65+.geojson').setStyle({fillColor: 'red'})
```

The style object supports all the path options decribed in this link:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-options

Comment: Thank you iH8. I tweaked as described and while the code didn't balk, there was no change to the default gray shading. Certainly no red. I also tried using a #****** value as well. Perhaps I have missed some earlier declaration to allow .setStyle to happen in the first place so I will keep trying. I haven't seen an example like mine so that tells me I am probably going about it the wrong way in general. Either way I'm learning much. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps you can setup a testcase on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), i'de be happy to take a look and see what's going on